# lib file works but dll file doesn't

Tags: c++, dll

As I usually use a series of classes, I want to make them as a link library so that I can use them easily.
What I do is that I generate two link files with visual studio 2013: `a.lib` and `a.dll`.
In my opinion, I just need use one of them, meaning that I don't need to use them together. To my surprise, if I import the `a.lib`(without `a.dll`) to a new project, everything goes well. But If I import the `a.dll`(without `a.lib`), I will get lots of error LNK 2001. Here is one of them:

```
Error   150 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall ExceptionAlertToLog::ExceptionAlertToLog(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,int,char const *)" (??0ExceptionAlertToLog@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HPBD@Z)  C:\Users\Thomas\Documents\bloomberg-api\MarketDataAgent\MarketDataAgent\DialogSubsBlp.obj   MarketDataAgent
```

It seems that I can't use this `dll` file, I can only use this `lib` file.

Comment: Have you seen [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6xx1b1z.aspx)? It might help you. Also verify that the DLL is in the same folder as the EXE, makes it more easy ;) (To automate that, you can select some option like "copy" in the compiler info, when you clicked on the dll in your project)

Comment: You have to link against the .lib file, and put the DLL in your executable folder (or in a system path).

Comment: @Banex  I have done like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my opinion, I just need use one of them, meaning that I don't need to use them together.

Your opinion is wrong, then.

Basically, you can create two types of libraries: static (`.lib`) and dynamic (`.dll`). However, `.lib` file is usually produced in both cases:

**1.** In cases of static library, `.lib` file is simply a composition of `.obj` files, containing definitions of all public types and symbols. It is linked into output `.lib`/`.dll`/`.exe`.

**2.** Dynamic libraries are produced with so-called [import library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682592%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It contains informations about location of symbols inside `DLL`, but not actual content. It is loaded at runtime from the `.dll` file.

Also:

> To implicitly link to a DLL, executables must obtain the following
>   from the provider of the DLL:
>
> - A header file (.h file) containing the declarations of the exported functions and/or C++ classes. The classes, functions, and data should
>     all have __declspec(dllimport), for more information, see dllexport,
>     dllimport.
> - An import library (.LIB files) to link with. (The linker creates the import library when the DLL is built.)
> - The actual DLL (.dll file).

Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14wsce5.aspx).

> But If I import the a.dll (without a.lib)

Final conclusion from the above is that you cannot do this. `a.lib` is used to link against `a.dll`. They are bound together and cannot be used separately. `.lib` file can be also substituted with export file. You should really read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkt2hd12.aspx).

Comment: If I debug a project with some link libraries, I must provide the `lib` files and `dll` files together. If I run an `exe`, I just need make sure that `dll` files are there. Am I right?

Comment: No, `.lib` is only required at the linking stage. During execution, only `.dll` file must be present. Debug information is a totally different thing and is stored in `PDB` file. Its generation is controlled by `Project properties` -> `Linker` -> `Debugging` (in case of Visual Studio).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand. I have only one question left. When I generate some link files(with vs2013), for example, there is one function that I want to make it as a link library. What I do is to create a win32 project and select DLL, then add this function's head file and cpp file in it. Finally, build it and I can get ONLY a `dll` file, there is no `lib` file. Then I change the "configuration type" of this project into ".lib". Rebuild and I get ONLY a `lib` file. In this case, I find that I can use this `lib` file without the `dll` file. So I think this `lib` file is

Comment: "1. In cases of static library, .lib file is simply a composition of .obj files, containing definitions of all public types and symbols". And if I try to use the `dll` file without the `lib` file, I get many `error LNK 2001`.

Comment: @Thomas It means, that no symbols were marked as exported and thus, no export library is needed. Symbols (types and variables), that should be exported must be marked with `__declspec(dllexport)` / `__declspec(dllimport)`. Search them in google.

Comment: Then I try like this: before generating link library, I add `__declspec(dllexport)` before each function. Build and I can `lib` file and `dll` file. Now I can use them together, meaning that I can import the `lib` file and make sure that the `dll` file is in the right directory. Everything goes well. So I think in this case, the `lib` is the second type: It contains infos about location of `DLL`.

Comment: I think you did not fully understand my post. Read it carefully and follow attached links. `.lib` as **static library** and `.lib` as **export library for `dll`** are **two totally different things**.

Comment: Now, I totally understand the second case: `lib` + `dll`. The `lib` tells the infos of the `dll`. So we need use them together. And also, I understand that for the first case, the `lib` is a static library, meaning that we can use it immediately (without `dll`). My question is: what is the `dll` in the first case used for?

Comment: In first case, there is no `.dll`, only `.lib`. It is probably a leftover from previous compilation. Remove it and rebuild *static library* target. No `.dll` will be produced.

Comment: OK, I got you. Thanks a lot.